# Calling a pointer to a function in a function as a parameter

Tags: c

I am trying to call a function that uses a pointer to a function as a parameter(compare), but I am having trouble properly calling this as I keep getting various warnings and errors such as, incompatible pointer types, init makes pointer to integer without cast, and the like. I am new to C and I haven't been able to find anything online that has helped me. Here is what I have and I think it is really close but I can't figure it out.

```
        int (*compare)(FRAME, FRAME) = &compareTo;
        removeNode(myQ, findNode(myQ, removeFrame,(*compare)(FRAME n, FRAME n1)));
```

FRAME is a struct type and compareTo function compares two FRAMES and returns an int (1, -1, 0) based on the comparison and removeNode is a function that finds a node in a queue and removes it. I don't have the removeNode function as it is coming from a locked header file so I cant post it. I thought I was creating it correctly based on other sources so I think the problem is where I am calling it?

```
    QueueNode *findNode(Queue *self, void *data, int (*compareTo)());
    void removeNode(Queue *self, QueueNode *p);
```

Thats all I have for these methods

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: While you're at it, take the [tour] and read [Ask].

Answer (score 1):

removeNode(myQ, findNode(myQ, removeFrame,(*compare)(FRAME n, FRAME n1)));

While passing a function pointer as an argument to a function, you should pass only function pointer. But you are passing function pointer along with its parameters. It should be like:

removeNode(myQ, findNode(myQ, removeFrame, compare);

Then in called function removeNode() you have to call the function pointed by compare along with its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your findNode() function:

```
QueueNode *findNode(Queue *self, void *data, int (*compareTo)());
```

And your removeNode() function is:

```
void removeNode(Queue *self, QueueNode *p);
```

Then calling removeNode() as you do:

```
removeNode(myQ, findNode(myQ, removeFrame, (*compare)(FRAME n, FRAME n1)));
```

Is wrong. The third argument of findNode takes a function pointer, you don't give it one. You should give the third argument the function pointer you created called "compare":

```
removeNode(myQ, findNode(myQ, removeFrame, compare); // compare is the function pointer
```